# How can I determine which FFmpeg file is being used

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, mjpeg

I want to study the code for the MJPEG decoder. I am trying to do that by using running commands for the decoder and then trying to identify which file performing the task of decoding.

I ran the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i heli.mjpg -vcodec copy newheli.avi
```

It produced the following output:

```
[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 372, current: 149; changing to 373. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 373, current: 150; changing to 374. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
....
....
....
....
....
....

[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 536, current: 215; changing to 537. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 537, current: 215; changing to 538. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 538, current: 216; changing to 539. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 539, current: 216; changing to 540. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x1818040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 540, current: 216; changing to 541. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  542 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2720kB time=00:00:54.20 bitrate= 411.1kbits/s    
video:2701kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.686601%
```

The starting part of the output is not visible. How can I find which .c file is performing MJPEG decoding? How can I isolate it, make changes to the .c and then run it?

EDIT:

Ideally, I would like to transfer the code for the MJPEG Decoder to an IDE like Qt and analyze the code there. I am struggling to understand how I can run the MJPEG decoder there.

Comment: the most direct route is to run it in a debugger (eg `gdb`).  you'll need a debug executable; depending on platform that may involve installing a `-dbg` package or compiling `ffmpeg` locally.

Comment: @quixotic Thank you for the reply. What do you mean by _compiling `ffmpeg` locally_? I am able to run `ffmpeg` and that is because I have compiled it already. I am not very familiar with this so please excuse me if my question is too basic.

Comment: often when software is installed from pre-built binaries, the packager has stripped debugging symbols out of the executable. this saves space but makes debuggers less clear.  you might need to recompile `ffmpeg` to get them; use the flag `--disable-stripping` when you rerun the `configure` script.

Comment: @quixotic Thank you for your help. I have run the command. How can I use this to transfer the code for the MJPEG decoder to Qt and then decode mjpeg files from there?